# Keep Changes Correctly by Entity Framework

Tags: database, entity-framework, concurrency

I have a problem in the entity framework and looking for a solution, the problem is this :

imagine a software with one form that contains staff data,

now two users open the same record at the same time in their own systems to edit its data,

the first user changes the name and saves his edit,

some seconds after the first user, the second user changes the phone number and save his edit,

*now which changes are registered in the database?*

**yes, the second change.**

as you may found out my problem, I need a solution to allow both changes happen correctly in entity framework ORM.

do I must handle such things in the UI section, or there is a way in the entity framework itself?

thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a broad and opinion-based question that's off-topic on Stack OVerflow. By default, EF only saves changed properties.

Comment: @GertArnold EF behavior is to only save changes, you're right, and this behavior makes a problem that I described in my question and I'm looking for a solution, and I think the best place for getting a solution is here.

Comment: *the best place for getting a solution is here* So go look for it. What you describe is named *optimistic concurrency* and there are plenty of posts pointing out how to apply it. At any rate, your question in its current form is too broad.

Comment: @GertArnold *optimistic concurrency control* is one of the solutions I'm looking for, thank you.I don't think that there were too many answers to my question situation.